# How change programmatically images sort order, in Magento

Tags: image, magento, gallery

I need to programmatically modify the sort order of existing product images.

I tried to search for a working solution but I found nothing.

I found how add an image in a media gallery via `addImageToMediaGallery`, but not how change properties (sort,label etc..) of existing media files.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
$prodID = '16';//product ID  
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api"); 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodID);
    $items = $mediaApi->items($_product->getId());
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $data =  array(

            'label'    => 'New Image Label',
            'position' => 3,
            'types'    => array('small_image'),
            'exclude'  => 0
        );
        $mediaApi->update($_product->getId(), $item['file'],$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With addImageToMediaGallery it is not possible to add position to the image,

you will need to use media->getBackend()->updateImage() after uploading the image,

but updateImage() needs second parameter image path of the uploaded image,

you can get it with media->getBackend()->addImage() it returns the filename, have a look at code for some hints

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(123);

$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);

$media_gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];

$backend = $media_gallery->getBackend();

$backend->afterLoad($product);

$count = count($product->getMediaGalleryImages()) + 1;

if($product->getImage() && $product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){
    $media_attributes = null;
}else{
    $media_attributes = array('image','small_image','thumbnail');
}
$filename = $media_gallery->getBackend()->addImage($product, $import, $media_attributes,false, false);
$attributes['media_gallery']->getBackend()->updateImage($product, $filename, array('position' => $count));

$product->save();
```

Comment: what is $import parameter in the addImage function?

Comment: Hi Altoids, $import is the absolute file path which has to be uploaded , i.e $import = /var/www/html/magento/data/product/import/image1.jpg";